# radiobutton passing value without reloading page

Tags: php, javascript, variables

is there a way of passing the value without reloading the page?

The value from the checked radiobutton is then passed to the session variable

```
$_SESSION['user']['moms'] = $_POST['radio_button'];


<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<label for="exkl">
<input type="radio" id="exkl" name="radio_button" onClick="this.form.submit();"  value="1"<?php if(($_POST['radio_button'] == 1) || ($_POST['radio_button'] == "")) {  print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> /> Exkl. moms</label>
<label for="inkl">
<input type="radio" id="inkl" name="radio_button" onClick="this.form.submit();" value="2"<?php if($_POST['radio_button'] == 2) { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> /> 
Inkl. moms</label>
</form>
```

thanks
linda

Comment: You could use an `XMLHttpRequest` to send and fetch data to/from the server without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont submit the form with onclick of the radio button, instead call a function, that checks whether the particular radio button is checked, and sends an ajax request to a php page, to store the radio button value in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via AJAX request which will call scripts on the server. The script will set the session variable. And the AJAX request can be executed on onchange javascript event.

Look on jQuery for example.